# Android AndroidAuto MapBox

Tags: android, mapbox, google-maps-markers, android-auto

I'm blocked on my Android Auto Application.
I want to add a custom marker to my screen map on Android Auto in the function onGetTemplate()
i using a PlaceListNavigationTemplate .
if someone could help me please .
thank you for your help

Comment: I think the android auto template is quite limited currently as there are not much documentation. And also for MapBox for Android Auto I see it's still under development `https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/guides/androidauto/`